# How to specify 'USE INDEX' in a JOIN using activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, indexing

Is there a way to force an index on a `JOIN` with active record in Rails, when multiple `JOIN`s are present?

I want the end SQL to be generated as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 USE INDEX('my_index')
ON table2.new_id = table3.new_id
```

Hopefully something like this is possible?

Comment: Which database? Usually the database makes the decision about whether to use the index or not. If you create the index on the right fields, and the database's query planner thinks that index makes sense for the query you've submitted, it will use the index.

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin That would be nice, but at least MySQL makes sometimes really terrible decisions when it come to use existing indexes.

Comment: Let's see the actual query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Perhaps we can change something to achieve the intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails does not support joins like that out of the box. But you can always write pass a string to `joins` that describes exactly what you want:

```
Post
  .joins(:author)
  .joins("INNER JOIN comments USE INDEX('myindex') ON comments.post_id = posts.id")
```

I used `posts`, `users` and `comments` instead of `table1` to `table3`, because `table1` etc. do not follow Rails naming conventions.